# python function parameter:using the either option ('*' and '=') in same parameter

Tags: function, parameters, python-3.5

I've been write a code but I have a problem in the function parameter. The function:

```
def seven_zip_file_extract(self,filename,*file ="" ):
    command = "7za e {}.7z"
    if *file=="":
        os.system(command)
    else:
        command = self.expand(command,*file)
        os.system(command)
```

that `*file=""`  is invalid syntax. How can I fix it?

I need the "*file" parameter because user could enters a input and that input could including more than one parameter but i need the define some thing for the user don't enter the input situation.Code for better explain:

```
def define_func(parameter1,parameter2="std_define"):
    pass
```

When i call that i need the enter parameter1 for able work but parameter2 is not necessary.Function will work either situation

```
define_func(val1)#Situation1


define_func(val1,val2)#Situation2
```

And '*' for the parameter representing one more value code:

```
def multi(parameter1,*parameters):
    pass
```

for instance to calling.

```
multi(val1,vala1,vala2,vala3,vala4)
```

that valax inputs will storge in that `parameter` value.I want to combine that to option.

And one more question.Is syntax of `if *file == ""` true?

Answer (score 0):

I've been solve it.That `*parameters` already does the job of that '='defining staff.That is the fixed code:

```
    def seven_zip_file_extract(self,filename,*file):
        command = "7za e {}.7z".format(filename)
        if file==None:
            os.system(command)
        else:
            command = self.expand(command,*file)
            os.system(command)
```